# Google maps autocomplete with JSF error with ÄÖÜ

Tags: jsf, google-maps-api-3, primefaces, character-encoding, autocomplete

we're using google maps autocomplete in our JSF application, but when we choose a name with öäü the backingBean gets eg. Ã as value. We have set our meta info of the site to utf-8, but this didn't help in this case.

we added it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;key=AIzaSyChQPYNPhodC79W6-oGzlVgQJEwfFMG_bs" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function addGMapAutoComplete(componentId) {
            var component = document.getElementById('createRequest:' + componentId);
            if (component) {
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(component);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and used as

```
<p:inputText id="pickupLocation"
                                            value="#{createRequest.pickupLocation}" required="true"
                                            onfocus="addGMapAutoComplete('location')"
                                            style="width:350px" />
```

can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with PrimeFaces. It's incorrectly using server's default encoding (which is often ISO-8859-1) for decoding POST request data of ajax requests, even though JSF/Facelets by itself already by default uses UTF-8 through all layers.

To overcome this, you need to manually set the POST request body encoding to UTF-8 by calling [`ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) with a value of `"UTF-8"` as early as possible in the request processing (before the parameters are ever parsed out of the POST request body). Most straightforward way would be using a servlet filter for this:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or, if you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) already, then just use its ready-to-use [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CharacterEncodingFilter) by adding the following entries to your webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```